# What is the regular expression to find a function containing specific text?

Tags: c++, regex, vim

*I'm asking this partially because it is something I would find very useful, but also to understand the syntax of the answer so I can make my own, creative, better regular expressions!*

So here's the question: I want to find a function in my code and I know part of the function name, and something that is inside of the function.  For example, given these functions:

```
Foo::bar1(Baz* baz)
{
    ...
    doWork();
    ...
}

Foo::bar2()
{
    ...
    beHappy();
    ...
}

Foo::hasAbar3Meat(Baz* baz1, Baz* baz2)
{
    ...
    beSad();
    ...
}
```

I want to find any of these "bar" functions that have the word "beHappy" in them, using *regular expressions*.  Keep in mind that these functions may call each other, and more generally, we don't know what is in the "...".  It may even be that more than one of these functions has "beHappy" in them.

EDIT: If it is not possible due to C++ not being a regular language, please explain why, and, if possible, give a solution with it's required restraints (such as, "there are no nested code blocks - using curly braces {} - in the code").

Comment: There may be answers but I'm pretty sure there won't be a single one.  Remember that you can have both inline and non-inline functions.  It's also going to be far from simple since a naive approach would be to search for anything containing the string, no spaces, followed by (.  That's not enough though since I could be doing math on a variable, etc...  Further, you might have potential false matches because of scoped overriding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretending that every function has correct indentation (there are no blocks of code that belong to the function and have indentation that is less or equal to indentation of function definition):

```
/\v(^\s*)regexForFunctionName\(.*[^;](\n\1\{)?(\n$|\n\1\s.*){-}\n\1\s.*\zs(whatToFind)/
```

(braces around whatToFind are here only for a bit more readability). For your particular example regex will look like this:

```
/\v(^\s*)[^(]*bar.*\(.*(\n\1\{)?(\n$|\n\1\s.*){-}\n\1\s.*\zsbeHappy/
```

It is better to remove the only `?` sign near `(\n\1\{)` in order to reduce probability that it captures code that is not a function definition. Depending on code style, more restrictions can be put on the part that ends with `(\n\1\{)?`. Note that if you use perl (and, probably, pcre), you can write an expression that will work with any valid C++ code, but this expression won't definitely be regular.

Comment: You, my sir, are amazing, and I award you 1 internets.  This solution works, and teaches much about regular expressions.  I chose your answer as it addresses my intention behind the question of solving the problem and learning regex.  I was not interested in a mathematically provable solution for all possible valid C++ programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\_` operator to search in vim (check `:h /\_`):

```
/Abar.*\_.*Sad/
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this solution?  I'm still not sure how that helps.

Comment: the `\_` part lets you search multilines, which I *thought* you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be any C++ code, then you can't use regular expressions.  Just think of what macros could do to your code.  This is valid C++ in the presence of macros

```
VOID_MEMBER_FUNCTION(Foo, bar)

    beHappy();

END_FUNCTION
```

The best assumptions to make to narrow the problem are to take advantage of coding and naming conventions.

Comment: though if it's only a macro issue (I hate your macro, by the way :p), one could search the preprocessed file.